# Kubernetes Dashboard, CrashLoopBackOff, user not in namespace "kube-system"

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I am trying to run Kubernetes dashboard. I've followed the steps in the [official wiki](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki).

Listing kube-system pods, I see:

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
kubernetes-dashboard-head-7478c547df-8bmxf  0/1  CrashLoopBackOff  1  12s
```

Restarting this pod causes the same crash. In logs it appears to have crashed because:

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard-head-7478c547df-8bmxf  
2019/02/26 23:15:57 Starting overwatch
2019/02/26 23:15:57 Using namespace: kube-system
2019/02/26 23:15:57 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2019/02/26 23:15:57 Using secret token for csrf signing
2019/02/26 23:15:57 Initializing csrf token from kubernetes-dashboard-csrf secret
panic: secrets "kubernetes-dashboard-csrf" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard-head" cannot get secrets in the namespace "kube-system": RBAC: role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard-minimal-head" not found
```

I don't fully understand how this can be. The `serviceaccounts` from this namespace container `kubernetes-dashbaord-head`:

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts -n kube-system
kubernetes-dashboard-head            1         8h
```

Since this `serviceaccount` (is this the same as "User"?) is listed in the `serviceaccounts` under namespace `kube-system`, why can't it get secrets from that namespace?

With recards to `RBAC: role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io ... not found`, is this related to this [issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/84)?

This is **not** on `minikube`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your case **is not** related to this [issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/84). This is just similar error that you get.

You need to have appropriate Role and RoleBinding which you probably don't have, that's why you get this error. 
You can verify with below command:

```
kubectl get role,rolebinding -n kube-system |grep kubernetes-dashboard-minimal-head
```

If you look at latest deployment [yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-head.yaml) file of Kubernetes dashboard from your installation guide, you will find below Role and RoleBinding resources.

```
# ------------------- Dashboard Role & Role Binding ------------------- #

kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal-head
  namespace: kube-system
rules:
  # Allow Dashboard to create 'kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder' secret.
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["create"]
...

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal-head
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal-head
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-head
  namespace: kube-system
```

But I am not sure how you deployed your deployment, so I would suggest you just delete your deployment yaml file, via

```
kubectl delete -f <your-deployment-file.yaml>
```

then apply latest which includes Role and RoleBindings for Dashboard

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-head.yaml
```

Then you can verify again via:

```
kubectl get role,rolebinding -n kube-system |grep kubernetes-dashboard-minimal-head
```

And check your pods of course.
I hope it would be useful

Answer (score 1):

As you error suggests `secrets "kubernetes-dashboard-csrf" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard-head" cannot get secrets in the namespace "kube-system": RBAC: role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard-minimal-head" not found`, you are running k8s-dashboard pod under `kubernetes-dashboard-head` serviceaccount in `kube-system` namespace. And the service account does not have access to `get/list` the secret `kubernetes-dashboard-csrf`.
Now to fix this problem you need to grant access to get that secret. You can do it in two ways: 1. allow the dashboard to run as `cluster-admin` role 2. just allow it to get that secret in that namespace.
The second option is much bette from a security point of view. To do this you need to add/edit your clusterrole (probably it is clusterrole since you want to view/edit objects cluster wide) that is bound to this serviceaccount (kubernetes-dashboard-head) as the following:

```
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resourceNames:
  - kubernetes-dashboard-csrf
  resources:
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - create
  - update
```